# one OPTIONS for all POST requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

Is there any way to have one `OPTIONS` request for all the subsequent `POST` requests.

The application communicates with the server by means of `POST` requests whenever required.There are many unrelated `POST` requests happening and for each `POST` request one `OPTIONS` is triggered to ensure `CORS`.Can we have one `OPTIONS`  for all these `POST` requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Max-Age), I believe you can accomplish this by setting the "Access-Control-Max-Age" header for an arbitrarily long duration of time. This field determines how long the results from the pre-flight OPTIONS request are cached for before an additional OPTIONS request needs to be sent, so by extending it you can limit how often OPTIONS requests are sent.